# Set default options for web application?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, window, web-application

I use web [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) quite allot, I have it bookmarked.

Every time I open it via my bookmark it and the website is loaded, a bunch of irrelevant settings are the default settings. Such as `PCRE2` RegEx flavour, with Global and Multi Line being enabled etc etc:
[image: |300]

So I have to enable `.NET` RegEx turn of Multi Line etc. I can only do with the mouse, I am on keyboard mostly, so its starting to become painful.

Are there any solutions out there, that will let me set these options once and then when I load my bookmark they are remembered or they are applied just in time.

I am not a web developer at all. So nothing comes to mind. I am thinking, with the proliferation of web applications, their must one or two solutions device for this  sort of issue, even if they are niche. Maybe even a bookmarklet?

I really want to adopt web applications more but this limitation is proving to be a hinderance.

Comment: RegexBuddy https://www.regexbuddy.com/

Comment: I did try to migrate this to [webapps.se] where I believe it is on topic but apparently it was closed as they think you were trying to develop a webapp. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171954/set-default-options-for-web-application?noredirect=1 Web app configuration and use is off topic here except where the problem is in your browser or computer.

Comment: @Mokubai Could this question be re-opened if it is edited to be not about a specific web-app?  If I'm reading it correctly, I think the OP is interested in answers that will apply to more than this single web-app.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I don't see how it could be edited in such a way. How to configure *any* webapp would likely still depend on the webapp and it would only really be on topic here if they used Autohotkey or their browser to run through the configuration options, but that requires knowing the webapp in question and how it stores settings still.

Comment: I suppose the option of "set up your browser to remember sessions when closed and then don't close that tab" could be on topic... but how to restore configuration for *any* website in a browser feels very vague, though potentially on topic. I wouldn't close it but I don't know if it would stay open. It might get closed as needing details.

Comment: @Mokubai just for future reference, Web applications would be the place to go for questions to do with user end web application usage? As RockPaperLz stated, I was really just looking for general purpose solution for web applications.

Comment: Yes, if you are having trouble using a Web application or something like a greasemonkey script or even bookmarklets for it, then [webapps.se] is the place as far as I know, or at least it was in the past. The problem here is that in its current form your question is specific to configuring that web application and not your browser which is why it was closed. "How do I configure this Web application?" Is different from "How do I save and restore the session data for this webapp in my browser?"

Comment: @Mokubai good to know, I will ask another question there then. Cheers.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for helping the OP get going in the right direction.